# Find the middle of a month

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

I need to find the moment that is in the middle of the month. Instead of dealing with whole months, I need the middle of one month and the middle of the following month. FYI, the use-case is for drawing charts, shading each side of the start of each month along a timeline; but that is irrelevant.

Whole days would be good enough resolution. Obviously months do not all have an even number of days, but an arbitrary rule like "first 15 days" would be acceptable. However, I will need to end up with date-time values, such as [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Currently I am using ±15 days as an arbitrary line for mid-month. Something like the following.

```
DateTime target = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ) ;
DateTime monthStart = target.withDayOfMonth( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay() ;
DateTime halfMonthPast = monthStart.minusDays( 15 ) ;
DateTime halfMonthCurrent = monthStart.plusDays( 15 ) ;
Interval halfAndHalf = new Interval( halfMonthPast , halfMonthCurrent ) ;
```

But arbitrarily using 15 days causes overlaps or gaps in months without 30 days. I would rather calculate the exact mid-point so a series of these Intervals would butt-up against each other neatly without gaps or overlaps. Ideally a Half-Open approach would be used, so beginning is inclusive while ending is exclusive.

`[mid-April to mid-May][mid-May to mid-June][mid-June to mid-July]`

Using either Joda-Time or java.time would be the preferred route.

Comment: Have you got any code showing you initial attempts?

Comment: Can you please share some code that can demonstrate what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please define exactly what you expect.  If you tell us what the expected answer would be for a 30-day month and a 31-day month, that should be good enough (we can figure out February).

Comment: `java.util.Calendar` is the standard API for date manipulation and calculation.  It should be quite sufficient for a task such as the one described.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Not any more. The Java 8 javadocs call `java.time` "The main API for dates, times, instants, and durations."  If you can't move up to Java 8, it's probably best to use Joda which is the basis for `java.time`, because then it should be easy to migrate when you can upgrade to JDK8.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the total number of days in a monthand then find the mid date of the month .

It also depends on whether you want 15th or 16th to be the middate for a month of 31 days .

```
int iYear = 2015; //Substitue for current year
int iMonth = Calendar.FEBRUARY; // Substitute for month
int iDay = 1;

// Create a calendar object and set year and month
Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(iYear, iMonth, iDay);

// Get the number of days in that month
int daysInMonth = mycal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // 28

//Use this if you want 15th to be mid date for a month of 31 days)
int midDay= (daysInMonth) /2 ; 
//Use this if you want 16th to be mid date for a month of 31 days)
int midDay = (int)Math.ceil(((double)daysInMonth)/2);

Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(iYear, iMonth, midDay);
```

Answer (score 2):

a) If you write

> Whole days would be good enough resolution.

then I recommend to **use `LocalDate`** for any intermediate calculation not `DateTime` (Joda-Time) or `ZonedDateTime` (Java 8). At the end you can always convert your `LocalDate` to a global timestamp using a timezone if you want. Doing so enables you to use Joda-Time-class `Interval` with dates converted to global timestamps. Java-8 does not offer an `Interval`-class. You might use Threeten-Extra which has a simple interval implementation. Both libraries lack a date interval class unfortunately.

However, writing such a simplified date interval yourself is easy (see also how simple the interval implementation in Threeten-Extra is). You only need one date per month. So you can use such a date as start date inclusive for the preceding interval and the same date as end date exclusive for the following interval from half month to half month. Using global timestamps is almost always an unnecessary complex step in such date-only scenarios involving any kind of timezone calculations (but is of course possible using expressions like [toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(zone)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-) in Joda-Time).

b) The final answer totally depends on how you define the midth of a month. Either you always choose the fifteenth, or the sixteenth or it is dependent on the length of a month which you can get this way:

**Joda-Time:**

```
LocalDate jd = new LocalDate(2012, 2, 7);
System.out.println(jd.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue()); // 29
```

**Java-8 (recommended by the author of Joda-Time):**

```
LocalDate d8 = LocalDate.of(2012, 2, 7);
System.out.println(d8.lengthOfMonth()); // 29
```

Then you can use formulas like for example (here Java-8-code):

```
LocalDate halfMonth = LocalDate.of(year, month, lengthOfMonth() / 2 + 1);
```